# psql select query does not work in powershell

Tags: sql, postgresql, powershell

Below is the SQL query i am trying to execute over PostgreSQL 11.

```
psql -U postgres -d Database -c "\COPY (select * from public.\"UserInfo\") TO 'C:\Users\z00\Desktop\b.sql' WITH DELIMITER ','"
```

Above command absolutely works on Command Line. It asks for password and then reports copied X rows.

However when i translate above to powershell as shown:

```
Start-Process "psql.exe" "-U postgres  -d Database -c `"\COPY (select * from userinfo) TO 'c\a.txt' WITH DELIMITER ','`""  -Wait
```

It wont work.

Below is the combinations what i have tried in Powershell; and none of them works.

```
Start-Process "psql.exe" "-U postgres  -d Database -c `"\COPY (select * from public.userinfo) TO 'c\a.txt' WITH DELIMITER ','`""  -Wait  

Start-Process "psql.exe" "-U postgres  -d Database -c `"\COPY (select * from public.`"userinfo`") TO 'c\a.txt' WITH DELIMITER ','`""  -Wait

Start-Process "psql.exe" "-U postgres  -d Database -c `"\COPY (select * from `"public`".`"userinfo`") TO 'c\a.txt' WITH DELIMITER ','`""  -Wait

Start-Process "psql.exe" "-U postgres  -d Database -c `"\COPY (select * from `"public`".`"UserInfo`") TO 'c\a.txt' WITH DELIMITER ','`""  -Wait
```

For all above cobinations; it reports

> stderr: ERROR:  relation "userinfo" does not exist
> LINE 1: COPY  ( select * from userinfo ) TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER ',...

However; when i change the select query to a different schema in powershell:

```
Start-Process "psql.exe" "-U postgres   -d Database -c `"\COPY (select * from information_schema.tables) TO 'c\a.txt' WITH DELIMITER ','`""  -Wait
```

It absolutely works.

I just can not understand why in powershell for same username, in same Database; it can not look/access public schema?
I tried setting default search path to "public" schema. No luck

Please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it took for me to was comparing the way CMD and Powershell do things and logging extensively in my script.

I just did a small change to the line as shown (bold text):

```
Start-Process "psql.exe" "-U postgres  -d Database -c `"\COPY (select * from \`"UserInfo\`") TO 'c\a.txt' WITH DELIMITER ','`""  -Wait
```

I just had to add `\` before the table name.

Answer (score 0):

In the first (working) example, you use `"UserInfo"`, which is case sensitive and contains two capital letters. In the other example, you use `userinfo` (with or without double quotes), which is lowercase. They are 2 different tables and the 2nd does not exist

Comment: Another good example why using quoted identifiers is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to mention. Even with case sensitive table name also does not work. Ill edit my original question.